# In what encryption type are passwords of wso2 user table (um_user) in wso2_shared_db stored?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

[According to the official documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/setting-up-databases/overview/) information about users of wso2 identity server reside in the **um_user** table of **wso2_shared_db**.
The question I would like to ask is in what encryption type passwords in the **um_user** are stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, user passwords are hashed using SHA256 with a random salt. The hashing algorithm is configurable with the `PasswordDigest` property like below.

```
[user_store.properties]
PasswordDigest = "SHA-256"
StoreSaltedPassword = true
```

PS: As a general practice, passwords are stored as hashes which do not allow fiding the plain text value. If passwords are encrypted, the plain text values can be found.